# Editing .LNK shortcut file special properties (e.g: Insert Mode, Font Weight, Cursor Size,...) with any programming language?

Tags: shortcut, file-properties

I want to edit the secondary/special properties that are applicable for certain target files only - in my case it's a batch file. I tried searching the web for an application to do this (command-line), but I could only find "shortcut file editors" that didn't stand up to their claims. I also tried editing the actual ".lnk" file and it was just some gibberish and the target file path, even in a hex-editor.
 I'm looking for a solution that can be in any programming language (or some software that edits secondary shortcut properties from the command-line), though it would be nice if it could be done with a scripting language.

Comment: You [use the `NT_CONSOLE_PROPS` structure](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/05/27/10421448.aspx).

Comment: Thank YOU Raymond Chen! This might be just what I was looking for!